# Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. But rejected by the Apple

Tags: avplayer, ipv6, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Apple has rejected my app because "all apps must support IPv6". I use `AVPlayer` to play stream.

> From Apple
>   2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
>   Performance - 2.1
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an Apple TV running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, we encountered an internet connection/data source error message.
>
> Next Steps
>   Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s), then revise and
>   resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on
>   how these features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>   For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous
>   version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>
> Resources
>
> For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.
>
> If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>
> - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
> - screenshots
> - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
> - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

Comment: So what happens if you test your application locally on an IPv6-only connection?

Comment: It is working fine as i expected.

Comment: have a look in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41462025/4944007. This was the issue for me.  Did not handle the *sad flows* for permission management which crashed the application.

Comment: My ap is alos using AVplayer to play stream audio and has also been rejected for the same reason although in all my tests it is working fine. Did you solve the probem finally?

Answer (score 0):

Link to a similar Q.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956700/4301118
Might help...