# App update getting rejected due to IPv6 network issue while using Alamofire

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store-connect, alamofire

My app uses Alamofire 3.42 to make our API calls along with a host of other frameworks. All the frameworks and our server are IPv6 compatible and yet our app fails for the Apple Testing team when tested in an IPv6 only environment.

We have tested our app in a NAT64 as prescribed by Apple with successful outcome. Our packet trace too shows IPv6 addresses being called successfully and yet our app update keeps getting rejected again and again.

When we submitted the app the first time, it did get rejected once for the IPv6 issue but got accepted the next time we submitted. Although, now we are trying to submit an update which keeps getting rejected with only this issue being quoted.

This has taken a lot of our time and would really appreciate some help with this. TIA!

Comment: Are you using a domainName or writing ip as http://xx.xx.xx.xx ? I don't think its related to alamofire

Comment: may be this discussion is helpful to u please visit this : https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/147579#147579

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari we are using a domain name.

Comment: @ravi.p We have gone through the above link and done everything necessary and submitted the outcomes to Apple. Yet nothing.

Comment: can u share exact error given by apple? Usually they point out to code which causing the issue. Try solutions provided on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222694/ipv6-apple-reject-app-ios

Comment: also submit a technical ticket with apple to get their expert help resolving this issue ( provided issue is not on server but pointed as within your code )