# iOS iTunes app rejected because of no support for IPv6

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, afnetworking, ipv6

I submitted a new version for my app to itunes and the app got rejected because of the following reason

[image]

Now I understand the new restrictions imposed by apple. My app should work in an IPv6 only network. But the problem here is that I cannot figure out why my app was rejected, because I tested it using the guide that apple provides([Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)) and my app functions as intended. I could not reproduce any problems that apple reported.

Furthermore, I read that the new IPv6 restrictions were imposed by apple on 1st June, 2016, while I have submitted a version to apple on 24th June which got approved.

But now they are complaining, could it be that apple technicians misunderstood something? Is there any way I can test my app other than the link above?

The only reason that comes to my mind is that my app still uses AFNetworking version 1. I'm in the process of updating to to version 3 right now. Would this solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is really an issue to take up with apple. They have a dispute resolution centre and each developer has two support requests you can raise with Apple per year where they can help you.

Comment: Okay I'll do it. But do you think that the older version of AFNetworking maybe causing the problem? Does version 1 support IPv6?

Comment: try solutions provided on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222694/ipv6-apple-reject-app-ios , open ticket with apple if any of above solutions doesn't work.

Comment: version 1 might be issue here. here is github link for 2.x support of afnetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3496 but i'm not sure if your issue is related to afnetworking or other

Comment: I also use ASIHTTPRequest framework in the application. Is it possible that it may be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUrlSession for making network request, not use any third party.

Comment: Doesn't AFNetworking use NSUrlSession to perform all network operations? I'm pretty sure it does