# Required iPv6 compatibility - iOS app rejected by Apple-AFNetworking

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, afnetworking, ipv6

After June 1, I submit my ionic app to iTunes connect and I got the message from apple.

> Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.

I have used `AFNetworking version 3.0` for API call.
and I am not using the hard coded IP Address in my app to call API. I have used `http://www.xxxx.com/API/login.php`

So now, what I have to change on mobile side and server side?

Please help me to find out the solution for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [required iPv6 compatibility - iOS app rejected by apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693256/required-ipv6-compatibility-ios-app-rejected-by-apple)

Comment: yes, but with  more details !!

Comment: Are you using reachability ? Check if thats using address instead of name.

Comment: I used  Reachability  for  Apple not for afnetworking   that  is fully support IPv6

Comment: can you please share code which you are using for calling function of reachability?

Comment: +(BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
    
}

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222694/ipv6-apple-reject-app-ios

Comment: thanks @nix, I read the post  very well. but I have the same problem that I use MacBook Air, so I can`t connect to Ethernet. they  solved the problem by changing the deployment  target from 9.3 to 9. but i am using 9 version  previously  .... please help me