# iOS App rejected by apple related to ipv6 connection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipv6

Apple rejected my app with the following message:

"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, an error was displayed when we tried to login.

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review."

On my tests I ran the app on the ipv6 network they help you create with a local machine on ethernet, and what happens is that I can't access the server for request due to "no internet connection".

I also tested the address I'm throwing my requests to and it looks like it is not IPv6 ready.

Could it be that the server side needs to be IPv6 ready?

I'm using NSURLSession for the tasks and my devices are running the latest ios.

Comment: your server side should be accessible form ipv6 environment.. are you using direct ip address in your rest api requests?

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:apple] tag as it's currently in the process of being removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPv6 - Apple reject app iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222694/ipv6-apple-reject-app-ios)

Comment: @suraj I'm using DNS name.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read this sounds like an issue we faced. We are in the UK which has limited IPv6 support at an ISP level. Apple rejected our app because our server which handled calls from the app was IPv4.

We resolved this by getting some IPv6 hosting from a company in the US and directing the requests from the app to it, and then across to our code on our IPv4 network here.